# How to correctly read data with cin?

Tags: c++

I am novice in c++ . I have the following definition:

```
typedef vec<int, 2> vec2d;
```

I can correctly input data by the following command:

```
vec2d myvec2d[] = { {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}};
```

But how can I read the same "myvec2d" with the same "typedef vec<int, 2> vec2d;" definition from keyboard (e.g. with `cin>>`)?

I have googled internet and have applied several tricks but I was not successful
to correctly do that(e.g.by push_back, etc..)?  Can somebody help me to solve this case?

Comment: What is `vec`? Do you mean `std::vector`?

Comment: It can't be `std::vector` (`std::vector` doesn't take two template arguments like that), more like `std::array`. Please give a [mre].

Comment: as shown in example they are a set of points (pairs) of integers defined by typedef

Comment: Consider `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>`.

Comment: Don't dual tag c++ and c. Refer to [the tag wiki of c++](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) for details.

Comment: The big unknown here is `vec`. No-one can explain how to read into a `vec` unless you explain what a `vec` is. This doesn't mean conceptually (presumably it's a vector of some sort), it means what operations does it support.

Comment: `vec2d data; std::vector<vec2d> myvec2d; while(cin >> data) myvec2d.push_back(data);`  Assuming `vec2d` supports `operator>>`.

Answer (score 1):

The iostreams library is capable of parsing numbers and not-numbers (i.e. strings). It is not by itself capable of parsing complex data like you're asking about there. Certainly it is not by itself capable of parsing C++ initializer lists.

Normally one would pick a structured data format such as JSON or YAML or XML and use an existing library to parse that format, then use some glue code to initialize the target object based on the data obtained from the library.